# Неправильный margin в css

Tags: html, css, margin

Возникла проблема при заполнении контейнера в `css`.

Ширина блока `div класса right / left = 40%` от родителя *`div с id`*, `margin` по ширине = **5%** `padding / border` нет.

Всего два блока, т.е. `40% * 2 +  5%  * 4 = 100%`, казалось бы, контейнер заполнен по ширине полностью, но на практике **2ой** блок вылезает за его границы. При этом, `css` не считает, что это `overflow`. Как можно это исправить, при том, что блоки должны быть равны и полностью помещаться в родительский контейнер?.

В ***Google*** решения не нашёл. `js` привязал чтобы можно было посмотреть весь сайт.

```js
//variables_________________________________________________
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]; //body
var blocks = [document.getElementById("_1"), document.getElementById("_2"), document.getElementById("_3"), document.getElementById("_4"), document.getElementById("_5")] // элементы, обозначающие слои
var currentLayer = 1; // текущий слой
var lastRotate = 0; //для колёсика
//commands__________________________________________________
makeDeep(blocks, currentLayer); //стартовое определение
body.addEventListener("wheel", onWheel);
//functions_________________________________________________
function makeDeep(elements, currentLayer) { //функция на определения видимости слоёв

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { //цикл по элементам на определение видимости

    var zindex = 6 - getStyle(elements[i], "z-index"); // получам z-индекс элемента

    if (zindex < currentLayer) { //проверка на текущий слой
      elements[i].style.display = "none"; //включаем невидимость невидимых слоёв
    }
    if (zindex >= currentLayer) { //проверка на текущий слой
      elements[i].style.display = "block"; //включаем видимость видимых слоёв
    }

  }
  var classCounter = 1;
  for (var i = currentLayer - 1; i < elements.length; i++) { //цикл по элементам на определение класса элемента
    elements[i].className = "_" + classCounter;
    classCounter += 1;
  }
}

function getStyle(el, styleProp) { //получаем з-индекс Элемента
  var x = el;

  if (window.getComputedStyle) {
    var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x, null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
  } else if (x.currentStyle) {
    var y = x.currentStyle[styleProp];
  }

  return y;
}

function onWheel(event) {
  if (event.deltaY < lastRotate) {
    if (currentLayer < 5) {
      currentLayer += 1;
    }
  }
  if (event.deltaY > lastRotate) {
    if (currentLayer > 1) {
      currentLayer -= 1;
    }
  }
  makeDeep(blocks, currentLayer);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#_1 {
  z-index: 5;
}

#_2 {
  z-index: 4;
}

#_3 {
  z-index: 3;
}

#_4 {
  z-index: 2;
}

#_5 {
  z-index: 1;
}

#_1,
#_2,
#_3,
#_4,
#_5 {
  position: fixed;
}

div>div {
  color: green;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 1%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.9);
  margin: 5%;
  height: 90%;
  width: 40%;
}

._1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 1s;
}

._2 {
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  transition: all 1s;
}

._3 {
  height: 60%;
  width: 60%;
  margin-top: 20%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  transition: all 1s;
}

._4 {
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  margin-top: 30%;
  margin-left: 30%;
  transition: all 1s;
}

._5 {
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  margin-top: 40%;
  margin-left: 40%;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Major+Mono+Display" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="_1">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>

<div id="_2">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>

<div id="_3">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>

<div id="_4">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>

<div id="_5">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вполне возможно, что я не совсем понял вопрос, но нельзя вложить эти блоки друг в друга и `position: relative;`, и оттуда уже задавать `margin` для вложенных блоков

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы считаете `margin`, но забыли о `padding`.

В селектор `div > div` и `.block`.

1. Добавил свойство `box-sizing: border-box`, что бы `padding` был частью ширины блока (`box model`).
2. Обнулил `font-size`, что бы убрать "белое пространство" между элементами с свойством `display: inline-block`.
3. Уменьшил ширину, так как использование отступов в `%` не всегда дает нужный результ. (Использование отступов в % нежелательно).

```js
//variables_________________________________________________
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]; //body
var blocks = [document.getElementById("_1"), document.getElementById("_2"), document.getElementById("_3"), document.getElementById("_4"), document.getElementById("_5")] // элементы, обозначающие слои
var currentLayer = 1; // текущий слой
var lastRotate = 0; //для колёсика
//commands__________________________________________________
makeDeep(blocks, currentLayer); //стартовое определение
body.addEventListener("wheel", onWheel);
//functions_________________________________________________
function makeDeep(elements, currentLayer) { //функция на определения видимости слоёв

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { //цикл по элементам на определение видимости

    var zindex = 6 - getStyle(elements[i], "z-index"); // получам z-индекс элемента

    if (zindex < currentLayer) { //проверка на текущий слой
      elements[i].style.display = "none"; //включаем невидимость невидимых слоёв
    }
    if (zindex >= currentLayer) { //проверка на текущий слой
      elements[i].style.display = "block"; //включаем видимость видимых слоёв
    }

  }
  var classCounter = 1;
  for (var i = currentLayer - 1; i < elements.length; i++) { //цикл по элементам на определение класса элемента
    elements[i].className = "_" + classCounter;
    classCounter += 1;
  }
}

function getStyle(el, styleProp) { //получаем з-индекс Элемента
  var x = el;

  if (window.getComputedStyle) {
    var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x, null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
  } else if (x.currentStyle) {
    var y = x.currentStyle[styleProp];
  }

  return y;
}

function onWheel(event) {
  if (event.deltaY < lastRotate) {
    if (currentLayer < 5) {
      currentLayer += 1;
    }
  }
  if (event.deltaY > lastRotate) {
    if (currentLayer > 1) {
      currentLayer -= 1;
    }
  }
  makeDeep(blocks, currentLayer);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#_1 {
  z-index: 5;
}

#_2 {
  z-index: 4;
}

#_3 {
  z-index: 3;
}

#_4 {
  z-index: 2;
}

#_5 {
  z-index: 1;
}

#_1,
#_2,
#_3,
#_4,
#_5 {
  position: fixed;
}

.block {
  font-size: 0;
}

div>div {
  color: green;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 1%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.9);
  margin: 5%;
  height: 90%;
  width: 40%;
  
  /*UPD.*/
  width: 39.2%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

._1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 1s;
}

._2 {
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  transition: all 1s;
}

._3 {
  height: 60%;
  width: 60%;
  margin-top: 20%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  transition: all 1s;
}

._4 {
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  margin-top: 30%;
  margin-left: 30%;
  transition: all 1s;
}

._5 {
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  margin-top: 40%;
  margin-left: 40%;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="_1" class="block">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>

<div id="_2" class="block">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>

<div id="_3" class="block">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>

<div id="_4" class="block">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>

<div id="_5" class="block">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать вот так:

css

```
.container {
      width: 90%;
      max-width: 1200px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 50px 0;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
      background: #cecece;
      justify-items: center;
    }
    .inner-block {
      width: 80%;
      border: 2px solid #fff;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 40px;
      line-height: 50px;
      text-align: center;

    }
```

разметка

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner-block">Left Block</div>
    <div class="inner-block">Right Block</div>
  </div>
```